# Normal Priority Builds Will Not Build in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs

I have two build processes setup in TFS 2010. One build starts when any developer checks code into TFS. The second build runs every night at 12:30am. I can see the builds have a priority of Normal in the queue. However no queued build ever is run until I change the priority to high. They will sit in the queue forever until the priority is changed.

It appears there is a normal priority build in the queue that is stuck. However I cannot find it. I can select `Any Build Definition`, `Any Status`, and `Any Build Controller` and not see anything but these builds queued up. I can run them all and the next day I have queued builds again. I say this because I see the Build Service is configured for port 9192, which leads me to believe there is or was another Build Service on port 9191.

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up removing a normal priority record from the table tbl_BuildQueue. This appears to have resolved the problem.

Comment: removing the row (just 1 row in my case) with an invalid definitionid worked for me.  posted details @ http://blog.sublogic.com/2011/07/07/dont-be-scared-of-foreign-keys/

Comment: Removing the priority is not the correct fix. See James Manning's solution.

Comment: James' blog article describes exactly what I did and what I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

I had this same problem where only builds that were "Above Normal" or High priority would actually build.

I tried restarting the build service, controller, and agents with no effect.  There were no errors in the Event Log.

It turned out that there were 2 rows in the tbl_BuildQueue table for build definitions that I had recently deleted.  Changing the status of those rows from 2 (Queued) to 16 (Cancelled) fixed the problem for me.

Here are some links that helped me figure this out:

http://networkprogramming.wordpress.com/2010/10/27/default-controller-cannot-be-deleted-because-there-are-builds-in-progress/

http://blog.hinshelwood.com/ghost-team-foundation-build-controllers

Answer (score 1):

Deleting rows from 'tbl_BuildQueue' fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with builds not... building!  Had to restart the controller/build agent which seemed to fix it.

While you're in there, the Build Configuration checks the Event Log for errors, anything showing up?